# How to apply the right firmware

Tags: network-interface

My distro (Fedora 36) is setting up the wrong firmware to my network card.

```
$ dmesg | grep -i r8169
[    2.043730] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: RTL8168ep/8111ep, 54:05:db:a1:3f:02, XID 502, IRQ 69
[    2.043738] r8169 0000:02:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9194 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    2.043860] r8169 0000:05:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    2.052595] r8169 0000:05:00.0 eth1: RTL8168h/8111h, 54:05:db:a1:3f:01, XID 541, IRQ 71
[    2.052601] r8169 0000:05:00.0 eth1: jumbo features [frames: 9194 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[    2.078445] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: renamed from eth1
[    2.093184] r8169 0000:02:00.0 enp2s0f0: renamed from eth0
```

`eth0` (in this case `enp2s0f0`) should be receiving `RTL8168ep/8111ep` instead of `RTL8168h/8111h`

cards are pretty much the same:

```
lspci | grep -i ether
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0e)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
```

is there some way to manually change this?
the issue is `enp2s0f0` slow down the internet after a while using it. so i'm looking for a fix and i think this could be it.

Comment: In your `dmesg` snippet, `eth0` (i.e. the card with the PCI ID 0000:02:00.0 = enp2s0f0) **is** being identified as RTL8168ep/8111ep, and according to [a table in the r8169 driver source code](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/net/ethernet/realtek/r8169_main.c#n92), no firmware at all will be loaded for that card model. Did you paste the IDs in reverse order by accident? The r8169 driver covers a lot of card model variants, and apparently "pretty much the same" is not "exactly the same".

Comment: i didn't pasted wrong. I found this that is the same case i have 
https://linuxlists.cc/l/1/linux-kernel/t/3794409/very_slow_realtek_8169_ethernet_performance,_but_only_one_interface,_on_thinkpad_t14.#post3794409

Answer (score 0):

Firmware doesn't change NIC model identification, it typically solves compatibility issues. Did you read the linked thread and did you do the checks mentioned there?

Comment: yeah i read it. seems the interface sucks.